# How to Represent HTML Table structure in Flex DataGrid or AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using Flex 4 and I need to render the data that resembles HTML Table with row span in a Flex component.  My inclination was to use a DataGrid but I believe that rowSpan is not supported for that component. I looked at the AdvancedDataGrid but the user does not want to have a tree-structure in any of the columns.  Looking to see if there are any hints/tips for modifying the DataGrid or AdvancedDataGrid  to  produce an "HTML Table with rowspan" look.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Grid Layout Container. The colSpan and rowSpan properties of the GridItem container let you create grid items that occupy multiple grid rows and columns.

Here is the documentation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layouts_09.html